# Xamarin starts simulator on mac instead of windows machine's

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Hi I have setup Xamarin on my visual studio on windows and I created my first app. Now I want to run it on simulator. I set my iOS project as the startup and ran it (I have connected to my mac mini using hotspot). When I run it, it starts the simulator on my mac instead of starting a simulator on my windows machine. What is the reason for this and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you still need to download and install Remoted iOS Simulator (for Windows)(if you still haven't):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ios-simulator

The remote iOS Simulator provides you with a way to test and debug iOS apps on the simulator entirely from Visual Studio on Windows.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

You should enable the Remoted iOS Simulator for Windows, navigate to Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings and check Remote Simulator to Windows.